# iOS localization not working for French Canada

Tags: ios, localization, nsstring, nslocalizedstring, multiple-languages

I have an iOS Application which was built in Xcode and uses Localization.string files with NSLocalStrings to handle localisation and different languages.

One of the languages is French, when we tested it on fr-FR, "French-French", it worked fine and no issues were reported by the testers. The translation is desired to be shown in French-Canada as well, when we select fr-CA all the strings are in English.

The app is also to be released in a number of Spanish and Portuguese countries, and I am concerned the app will appear in English in different South American countries etc.
(I am familiar with how to localise in Android and Windows applications, but can't work out how to resolve this in iOS)

**How can we ensure that the localisation is applied to all versions of the languages?**

Comment: Hi @Kirit, that is currently how we are using localisation. It is currently working for: English(en), French(fr-FR), Finnish(fi), German(de), Spanish(es), Swedish(sv), and Portugese(pt-BR). The issue is with fr-CA not showing the French translation, also just found that while pt-BR is working, pt-PT shows English

Comment: Hi @Luke, did you figure out what was the problem? I am facing the same issue after 5 years :-D

Answer (score -1):

I think you don't have to add diffent localizable string for french-french[fr-FR] or french-canada[fr-CA]; only **french[fr]** (in localizable string file fr.lproj) is enough if you want to show the same text for all in french.

And also for [pt-BR] you can use **[pt]** if both texts are same portuguese format.

Otherwise, you have to add(+) those languages manually from project settings info for **localisations** and load different text file for those.

You can try this tutorial to verify your steps of localization: [iOS Localization Tutorial](https://medium.com/lean-localization/ios-localization-tutorial-938231f9f881)